# How to display images from SQLite database browser in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-imageview

I have a 3 fields in 1 table.. that is: Title, Details, and Image. I made The Field 'Title' into a ListView. and I hope, when the listview is pressed, will be display 'Title' as Textview and 'Image' as Imageview. But, I do not know how to display the image. I'm not found Appropriate tutorials, everywhere ~
How to display images from SQLite database browser to Android Studio?

Comment: Your question is not clear, "How to display images from SQLite database browser to Android Studio",  What do  you really want to do?

Comment: @AndersonCSilva I Want to retrieve images from a database (SQLite), the image will be displayed when I pressed listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first all, do you need create a `Table` with `Blob` column, after this, do you need to convert your `Image` from (`bitmap`) to byte.

This is way you can save and retrieve image to `SQLite` on Android App.

See some example here:

[insert-image-in-sqlite-and-display-in](http://geekonjava.blogspot.com.br/2013/09/insert-image-in-sqlite-and-display-in.html)

I hope it helps!